# Upload laravel project to server subfolder

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to laravel. I have develop a project in laravel and now i want to migrate it on client's server. but as per client's requirement he want to upload all code in sub folder like my domain is xyz.com then client want to upload whole project in "xyz.com/subfolder". I have upload all my code in sub folder but when i am going to access then nothing is display. i am not able to access site. I have change server.php file to index.php file. also I have copied .htaccess file from public and write below code in it.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

can anyone guide me how can i make it accessible.

Comment: Have you also copied all the vendor stuff etc?

Comment: yes i have upload all files

Comment: I have check in console it shows me internal server error 500

Comment: Use the last PHP version, And try again?